# Can I solve vertex limit by splitting meshes to submeshes? (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am generating huge mesh with 50k+ vertices and I am not sure if I understand submeshes correctly.

Question #1: Would splitting mesh to multiple submeshes work?

Question #2: Do they behave like entirely new mesh? Is there some difference between creating multiple submeshes and creating multiple meshes?

Question #3: If answer #1 is yes, are triangles in each submesh indexed from 0?

Comment: The explanation of submeshes on Unity Answers may be useful if you happen to circle back to this in the future. https://answers.unity.com/questions/684995/what-is-a-submesh.html

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I can use [32 bit buffers](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rendering.IndexFormat.html).